# Does azure pipelines allow custom action like AWS codepipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Does azure pipelines allow custom action like AWS codepipeline?

I want to create a job worker that will poll azure pipeline for job requests for this custom action, execute the job, and return the status result to azure pipeline.

Something similar to - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html

Answer (score 0):

**Tasks** are the building blocks for defining automation in a build or release pipeline in Azure DevOps. There are many [built-in tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops) to enable fundamental build and deployment scenarios. If the existing tasks don't satisfy your needs, you can always build a [custom task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops). Check [Task types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more details.

In addition, [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) offers a number of extensions; each of which, when installed to your subscription or collection, extends the task catalog with one or more tasks. Furthermore, you can write your own [custom extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/?view=azure-devops) to add tasks to Azure Pipelines.

**Azure Pipeline Agents**

When your pipeline runs, the system begins one or more jobs. An agent is computing infrastructure with installed agent software that runs one job at a time.

You have two options here to choose from: **Microsoft-hosted agents** or **Self-hosted agents**

An agent that you set up and manage on your own to run jobs is a self-hosted agent.  [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.

However, before you install a self-hosted agent you might want to see if a Microsoft-hosted agent pool will work for you. In many cases, this is the simplest way to get going.

With [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), maintenance and upgrades are taken care of for you. Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. Microsoft-hosted agents can run jobs directly on the VM or in a container. Azure Pipelines provides a pre-defined agent pool named **Azure Pipelines** with Microsoft-hosted agents.

You can try it first and see if it works for your build or deployment. If not, you can use a self-hosted agent. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) doc for more details.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the Tasks. Thought it's not what I am looking for. Let me put the question in different words. In azure pipelines, the pipeline agent processes the task or the steps. Now Instead of pipeline agent, I want to use my own job worker in other words my job processor. I will pull the agent queue from my custom job worker and process the job. Is that possible in azure pipelines? I hope what I say make sense.

Comment: @RahulParikh It sounds like you're looking for Self-hosted agents. Edited my answer with more details. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> I will pull the agent queue from my custom job worker and process the job. Is that possible in azure pipelines?

Based on my understanding of code pipeline and Azure devops, I am afraid what you said should be meaningless.

According to the document [Create and add a custom action in CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html), we could to know that:

> AWS CodePipeline includes a number of actions that help you configure
> build, test, and deploy resources for your automated release process.
> If your release process includes activities that **are not included in
> the default actions**, such as an internally developed build process or
> a test suite, you can **create a custom action for that purpose and
> include it in your pipeline**.

But for Azure devops, we do **not** need to create a job worker that will poll CodePipeline for job requests for this custom action. That because the whole process of build/release can be customized. We do not need to add a job worker for additional custom actions.

Azure devops provide a lot of templates when we create the pipeline, we could modify the pipeline directly in the pipeline to add/remove or update the task:

[image]

[image]

Even we can completely start with a blank pipeline and completely customize the entire build/release process.

So, we do not need to create a job worker for the custom action, just modify your pipeline directly.